# Как сделать такой блок адаптивным?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

На одном [сайте](http://35.170.225.58/) есть такой блок:

[image]

[image]

Пробовал медиа-запрос с `display: block` для элемента, но не работает. Как сделать такой блок адаптивным?

Comment: Можно код примерный?

Comment: Код есть на сайте, сейчас добавлю

Comment: Не, там порнуха)

Comment: Ходить по непонятным ссылкам опасно, тем более, когда там что-то непонятное. К тому же сайт потом может измениться и ссылка станет нерелевантной к вопросу. Приведите весь нужный код текстом в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант сделать так:

```
.av-countdown-cell {
    display: contents;
}

#top .av-countdown-style-1 .av-countdown-cell-inner {
    width: 90px;
}

.av-countdown-style-1 .av-countdown-time {
    width: 75px;
    max-width: 80px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s.: На будущее советую скрывать "контент" своего проекта.

Comment: я такого раньше не видел , а что такое `contents` ? как он себя ведёт ?

Comment: Не работает у меня этот способ

Comment: Сам элемент не создает никаких боксов, но его потомки и псевдоэлементы создают боксы как обычно. В плане генерации боксов и раскладки элемент должен рассматриваться так, как будто в дереве документа его заменили его потомками и псевдоэлементами.

Иными словами, потомки элемента ведут себя как соседи его соседей, становясь с ними на один уровень, сам элемент перестает быть промежуточной оберткой для них.

Источники:
[css-live.ru](http://css-live.ru/articles/display-contents-practice.html) и 
[спецификация](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#box-generation)

Comment: Жаль, что в IE этот способ не работает...

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью `float`

```css
.time-block > .block {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="time-block">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

или же `inline-block` стоит учесть что у инлайн-блоков появляется обступ между блоками в 2 пикселя.

```css
.time-block>.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin:-2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="time-block">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```